# How do i replace newline character with <br /> without creating two line breaks

Tags: html, asp.net, dotnetnuke, line-breaks

I add Dynamic content to  my web page in Dotnetnuke using a module. So i am creating a Html Div and adding content to it before adding it to the page.

I am replacing line breaks in the content with `<br />` tag. Unfortunately when i do so it adds two line breaks instead of one. I dont know if this a dotnetnuke quirk. if yes, how do i overcome this?

```
HtmlGenericControl ModuleBody = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
ModuleBody.Attributes.Add("class", "panel-body");
ModuleBody.InnerHtml = Regex.Replace(pair.Entry.Value, "\n", "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the value of `pair.Entry.Value` has `\r\n` as its line break character, rather than just `\n`.

Try this instead:

```
ModuleBody.InnerHtml = Regex.Replace(pair.Entry.Value, "\r\n", "<br />");
```